# unable to bootstrap command in Marklogic 9.0-5 from roxy 1.7.3

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to run bootstrap command from roxy 1.7.3 to configure Marklogic 9 database set up it showing below error

> ERROR: 500 "SECURITY-BADREQUEST (err:FOER0000): Your session has been terminated
>    by another login.  Refresh Query Console to create a new session."
>
> ERROR: {"error":{"format-string":"SECURITY-BADREQUEST (err:FOER0000): Your sessi
>   on has been terminated by another login.  Refresh Query Console to create a new
>   session."}}

Here we are using app-type=hybrid & server-version=9

Any one please suggest what need to be fix it here?

Answer (score 1):

Roxy version 1.7.3 doesn't recognize server-version 9, and falls back to server-version 8 behavior, which isn't fully compatible with ML 9. You'll need to upgrade. That should be fairly straight-forward:

```
./ml upgrade --branch=master
```

HTH!

Note: there is a slight chance you might hit issues when upgrading, similar to https://github.com/marklogic-community/roxy/issues/802. Create a github ticket if you do..